# Telerik reporting in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can anyone help me in implementing telerik reporting in ASP.NET MVC project?

Answer (score 6):

The way I have reporting implemented is without a viewer, instead a user is presented with a "pdf" report, that can be downloaded.

Here is a scenario, user purchases a product online and at the end of the check out process a receipt is presented via a Telerik report.

1. Add the references to the Telerik reporting assemblies in your project.
2. Create a report. Telerik TV has some great tutorials on getting started with [Telerik reporting](http://tv.telerik.com/products/reporting).
3. Controller would make a call to the repository, and serve the byte stream back to the browser.

   ```
   public virtual ActionResult DownloadReceiptReport(Order model)
   {
        byte[] contents = ShoppingCartRepository.GetReceiptReport(model);
        return File(contents, "application/pdf", "Receipt.pdf");
   }
   ```
4. In your repository create a function to generate the report, in this case the report isn't directly linked to a sqldatasource, the data source is being supplied an objectdatasource component:

   ```
   public byte[] GetReceiptReport(Order order)
   {
       Telerik.Reporting.ObjectDataSource objectDataSource = new Telerik.Reporting.ObjectDataSource();
       objectDataSource.DataSource new PurchaseReceiptReportModel() 
       {
           CustomerName = order.CustomerName, 
           Total= order.Total, 
           PurchaseDate= DateTime.Now
       };

       PurchaseReceiptReport report = new PurchaseReceiptReport();
       report.DataSource = objectDataSource;

       ReportProcessor reportProcessor = new ReportProcessor();
       RenderingResult result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", report, null);
       return result.DocumentBytes;
   }
   ```

In the end, user will receive a download pop-up window with a pdf report.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is a really great piece of advice. Thanks a million for that.

Answer (score 4):

There are couple of things that you need to do:
1. You must use ASPX.NET form rather then Razor view.
2. You must render your .aspx page as a partial view within your controller
3. You will have to override few css classes and and new ones for the Report to render properly in the browser.
Check out this video tutorial for more details:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-iA05KpDFM

Or use this examples and source from here:
http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/reporting/general/using-telerik-web-reportviewer-in-asp-net-mvc-application.aspx

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Yes the telerik report viewer can be used.  This may help: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/reporting/telerik-reporting/reportviewer-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx

I think you need the following:

- use a web form, not a view (it might work with a view, cant' remember
- with runat='server'

It may have changed since I last used it (with MVC support), but this is how I implemented it.  It's been a little while though.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternate solution for how to generate a pdf fromt the report which I came up with after trying the above solution but I needed to pass a parameter and couldn't make it work using the report object in the above example. All my code is in a controller action, I suppose moving it to the repository would be worth doing but for the sake of this post I'm keeping it simple.

The PackingList report was created as per `Telerik` examples and is located in a report Library called LogisticsReports. I have a using statement on the top of the controller "using Telerik.Reporting;"

```
public ActionResult ShippingPackingList(int id = 0)
    {
        var instanceReportSource = new InstanceReportSource();
        instanceReportSource.ReportDocument = new LogisticsReports.PackingList();
        instanceReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Parameter("ShippingHeaderID", id));
        Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor reportProcessor = new Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor();
        Telerik.Reporting.Processing.RenderingResult result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", instanceReportSource, null);
        byte[] contents = result.DocumentBytes;
        return File(contents, "application/pdf", "PackingList1.pdf"); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is released a preview of the beta HTML5 Report Viewer - [Bringing the Power of HTML5 to Telerik Reporting](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/13-09-23/bringing-the-power-of-html5-to-telerik-reporting)